# Split dataframe column at specific words

Tags: python, pandas

One column in my dataframe is a long string. I want to split out portions of the string into its own column based on a few different words. What would be the best way of doing this? Example below of what the data in the column looks like, and what i want to pull out.

Original Data:

ABC - Company Name Company Name Week 31 Drop 1

XYZ - Company Name Company Name Extra Cycle 9 Drop 2

I want to pull out the number after week and cycle. The number of words may vary by row but week and cycle will always be followed by a number. How would I pull out the number next to either word and put it in the same new column?

I have been able to pull out one or the other (the number after week *or* cylce), but not both into the same column. Havent gone down the route of directly iterating over the dataframe since thats not ideal

What i want the data to end up like:

| String | Number |
| --- | --- |
| ABC - Company Name Company Name Week 31 Drop 1 | 31 |
| XYZ - Company Name Company Name Extra Cycle 9 Drop 2 | 9 |

Got it part of the way with the code below (can handle two words) but cant handle a third

`df['cycle_num'] = df.project_name.str.extract('((?<=Cycle|Week\s).[0-9]+)', expand=True)`

I get the following error if i try to add a third word:

`re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 I believe i have provided a specific technical problem. how to use pandas to split a number off following specific words (week, cycle, etc) in a column of a dataframe. what comes before or after im not asking for help with so i think this is as specific as I can get. If you need clarification on something please let me know and i can expand, but i am not sure what is needed without input

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up finding a solution. this worked for me. not sure if this would lead to any exceptions (other than them just showing up in other locations) but it hasnt so far. no longer using week but capturing the number after other words/characters. I think I still had an issue with Joey's answer but it led to in the right direction if im remembering correctly

```
df['cycle_num'] = df.project_name.str.findall(r'(Cycle |#|Cycle |# |Cyc|Cyc )(\d+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['ABC - Company Name Company Name Week 31 Drop 1'],
                   ['XYZ - Company Name Company Name Extra Cycle 9 Drop 2']],
                  columns=['a'])
```

[image]

Example code for new column:

```
import regex as rx
splitter = lambda x: int(rx.findall(r'(Week|Cycle) (\d+)', x)[0][1])
df['b'] = df.a.apply(splitter)
```

[image]

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you posted says that look-behind needs a fixed-width pattern. This means that you can only use words with the same length in your look-behind. The first two words, `Cyle` and `Week\s`, have the same length. The problem with the third word only occurs if you add a word that is shorter or longer.

To solve this issue you can `or` multiple look-behind instead of the words. I created an example which contains a third word of different size:

```
import pandas as pd

# Generating the data frame
rows = ['ABC - Company Name Company Name Week 31 Drop 1',
        'XYZ - Company Name Company Name Extra Cycle 9 Drop 2',
        'XYZ - Company Name Company Name Extra SomeOtherWord 432 Drop 2']
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.columns = ['project_name']

df['cycle_num'] = df.project_name.str.extract('(((?<=Cycle\s)|(?<=Week\s)|(?<=SomeOtherWord\s))[0-9]+)', expand=True)[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0  ABC - Company Name Company Name Week 31 Drop 1           31
1  XYZ - Company Name Company Name Extra Cycle 9 ...         9
2  XYZ - Company Name Company Name Extra SomeOthe...       432
```